# Generic Ways to aggregate and present data

Tags: web-applications, data

Imagine a standard shop system were users buy stuff and products are being stored and presented. The platform saves and manages a lot of data.

Now there are managers who want to be able to see this data e.g. via excel sheets, but in generic ways, some want to see all users with their names, some without, some want to see each product in one column and user ids who bought this product in another column.

Are there good ways to create such a presentation/aggregation layer (however you may call it)? It seems like the only option would be to allow the user to create SQL Queries via an easy interface by themselves (provided that security issues like SQL injection is properly dealt with).

Thanks

Comment: If you're a Microsoft shop, look at SSRS - Sql Server Reporting Services.  However, do NOT allow business uses to create ad-hoc reports.  They'll mess them up, get conflicting answers, then blame you.  Either that, or they'll create 600+ reports and expect you to maintain them.  Care to guess how I know?  :-)

Comment: sadly (or luckily?) no microsoft software being used. The general problem is the ability to create excels structured at will, from the data of the database for non-tech people.

Answer (score 2):

> Imagine a standard shop

Well here you've lost me. I know far to many shops.

> managers who want to be able to see this data

The important bit here is you've never mentioned the managers wanting to do any input in their reports. This is good.

> Are there good ways to create such a presentation/aggregation layer

Sure, it's called data science. Stop trying to offer everyone a custom view into your database directly.  Give them a data feed. Let them hire a data science guy to present that in wonderful ways. Or just let them import it into excel and do as they like.

Now all these observers have what they need and are leaving your DB the hell alone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, a professional taking care of this would be certainly the best solution though sadly it is currently not an option. :-(

Comment: @Chris why not? At least impress upon them that what their asking for is now an entire branch of computer science. If it's just not in the budget then give them the feed and tell them to import their little harts out with the understanding that spread sheets are supported by whoever wrote them. Just keep the feed consistent and the rest is their problem.

Comment: I'll definitely do that yes. Generally the problem is that currently we are writing custom exporting/transformation scripts everytime somebody wants certain other data in his excel sheet or an additional column containing some information. The thought was to create some kind of "Sheet Builder" to let them do this by themselves. Though I guess that this would eventually lead into the direction of building some kind of Query language or DSL.